# Reactive Extensions (Rx) in windows Phone Mango

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, system.reactive

what is meant by Reactive Extensions(Rx). How its helps me to develop applications in windows phone mango?? Is it q framework or helper library? What is the role of this (Rx) in effective application development in WP. Mango. Can any one please suggest me some links to learn the technique,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at this:
[Rx-Reactive Programming for Windows Phone](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/28/rxreactive-programming-for-windows-phone/)

and here you can find a lot of video here: [Channel 9 Rx](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/rx)

Rx is a framework to help you programm and link async/event based behaviour inside your code using LINQ-expressions. It can really help you with all the events and async-calls you can do in WP7 and silverlight - give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I [wrote a blog post](http://windcape.posterous.com/reactive-extensions-and-how-i-used-them-in-my) about the use of Reactive Extensions. It might also be of interest.